# How can i update target Android API using ionic 5

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

While trying to upload my .aab file to Google Play Console I am getting the following error:

```
Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31
```

I am using ionic 5 to build cross-platform mobile apps. So I guess I should not touch any native android configuration to make it work. Does anyone know how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic wrote a blog post, which should answer your questions.

https://ionic.io/blog/update-your-target-android-api-level-by-november-1